# Increment file size after convert image with PHP imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I have a function to convert jpg image to tiff image, keep the original size and quality. I used Imagick class to do that. Convert success but image size has increment too much. My original image was taken from iPhone with 2.6Mb after converting, it increment to 36.6Mb.

I had tried to use some PHP image manipulation libraries like [Intervention/image](https://github.com/Intervention/image) but nothing change.

I also test convert original jpg to new jpg and file size increment from 2.6Mb to 3.3Mb.

My code here:

```
$image = new \Imagick('image_path_file.jpg);
$image->setImageFormat("tiff");
$image->writeImage("path_new_file.tiff");
```

Have any options that can help Imagick not increment file size too much?
Thanks you ‍♂️

Comment: Why do you need to convert the images in the first place? Could you give us a bit more information about what you are trying to achieve in the first place? We might find or may know a better way to achieve it instead of Imagick.

Comment: TIFF file size is larger than JPG. This is normal. JPG to JPG file size can be larger or smaller depend on [quality setting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setcompressionquality.php).

Comment: I’m guessing that the TIFF isn’t using internal compression, try calling `setCompression` and using `imagick::COMPRESSION_ZIP`, or maybe LZW. This doesn’t change the quality in any way.

Comment: @PeriklisKakarakidis, That is just a simple function to convert images to tiff format.

Comment: @vee, Thanks, I try to used `$image->setCompressionQuality(50);` but nothing change, still 36.6Mb

Comment: @ChrisHaas, Thanks, that reduce file size to 13Mb :D

Comment: Try setting compression, then the quality, I think the latter becomes the strength of the ZIP algorithm. Don’t use `setImageCompression` unless you want to destructively compress the image, however.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, thank you, I got it.